# How to add code template which will be available to be added later to my later spring boot projects readily?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

i want to **create a setup** in which i have template code(s) which when starting a new spring boot project can be easily added into the new project.
I tried finding stuff on net which mostly showed adding a custom service or a dependency in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Spring Boot project that contains nested maven projects is called the multi-module project. this approach give you option to add or remove module (addon project or template)